# Return statement syntax

Tags: java

What do the symbols '?' and ':' mean in a return statement?

```
public boolean isItBigger(BigInteger num1, Long num2) {
        return num1 == BigInteger.ONE || num2.intValue() > 0 ? true : false;
    }
```

Also I think I have seen them in if statements.

Comment: Is the same as `return (num1 == BigInteger.ONE || num2.intValue() > 0);`

Comment: Yes now I understand, thanks everyone for respond :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `?` and `:` is Java's [ternary conditional operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) (JLS 15.25).  The result of the expression

```
aBoolean ? expr1 : expr2
```

is `expr1` if `aBoolean` is `true`, else it's `expr2`.

In this case, it could be left off because it's unnecessary:

```
return num1 == BigInteger.ONE || num2.intValue() > 0;
```

Comment: I understood now, and you're right, is unnecessary the true-false expression at the end. Thanks to everyone else for respond.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a). The  following are equivalent

```
if (x == y)
   x = 2;
else
   x = 3;
```

and

```
x = (x == y) ? 2 : 3;
```

Your example code is silly though. First they're checking if the expression evaluates to true. Then, if it does, they return true. They could just as well return the result of expression itself, like so:

```
return num1 == BigInteger.ONE || num2.intValue() > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

this is called conditional/ternary operator

```
boolean-expression ? do-this-if-true : else-do-this
```

it is shortened form of

```
if (boolean-expression) {
do-this
} else{
do-this
}
```